# Return statement in javascript doesn't exit the function?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I wrote a simple function to `sort` objects not expecting it to work but it does:

```
function sortObjs(objArr,field) {
    objArr.sort(
        function(a,b) {
            if( isNaN(a[field]) ) {
                return a[field].localeCompare(b[field]);
            } else {
                return parseFloat(a[field]) - parseFloat(b[field])
            }
        }
    );

    return objArr;
}
```

When I call this function I get my sorted objects without issue. But I was not expecting it to work because I thought the first two return statements would exit the function before it got to the last statement: `return objArr`.

Comment: They return from the inner function, not from `sortObjs`.

Comment: you can't cancel a sort() mid-way... (without  `throw`)

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not trying to cancel a sort mid-way I'm checking if the property to sort on is a number or string before sorting. Am I doing something wrong? worked ok when I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why the inner function's `return` statements would not have an effect on the return statement in the outer scope, you need to understand how the `Array.prototype.sort()` function works.

The function [**arr.sort([compareFunction])**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), takes a function as a parameter.

> compareFunction
>       Optional. Specifies a function that defines the sort order. 
>       If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, 
>       according to the string conversion of each element.

- The logic you write inside the `compareFunction` gets executed when
  the java script engine tries to compare two elements   during its
  comparison operation.
- Hence for each comparison that it makes, the function would return a
  value, based on which the elements   would be ordered.
- This implies that the `compareFunction` that we pass on as a parameter
  would be used to just obtain a value based on which two elements can
  be compared  and **not exit** the sort operation, leave alone exiting the
  outer function.

Having said this, the code `return objArr;`, takes no effect, since the array would be sorted  [in place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

You have a nested function.  The first two returns will exit the inner function, while the last one will exit the outer one.

**EDIT:**

You can think of function returns as "replacing" the function with the returned value.  For example:

```
var i = getSum(1, 3);

function getSum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The function getSum returns the sum of a and b.  The line `var i = getSum(1, 3)` will execute the lines of code contained in the function with `a = 1` and `b = 3`.  The value that is returned "replaces" the function call.  So now the line of code looks like `var i = 4;`.  Although this is not **exactly** how it works, it's a good way to conceptualize it.  This is a special case because you aren't actually running the inner method here, you're passing it as a variable.

Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Oh duh. That was obvious. I think I might ask another more general question about how closures work because I'm still a little confused. The value that is returned in the first return statements is returned to objArr?

Comment: @red888: No, the `sort` function takes a function as the parameter. The return values from the inner function return values to the sort function.